# git clone connection refused on personal gitlab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I try to build gitlab by docker

```
~$ git clone ssh://git@serverIP:5022/sungjinseo/test.git

Cloning into 'test'...
ssh: connect to host serverIP port 5022: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

~$ ssh -T git@serverIP -p 5022

Enter passphrase for key '/home/greatseo/.ssh/id_rsa':

Welcome to GitLab, @sungjinseo!
```

I can access ssh by the port but it does not work to connect by `git clone ssh`

I can not use `git clone` by "http" call. I have to only reach gitlab page by ip. cuz I set my server bandwidth 5000-6000 by router.

[image: ssh works well but git clone not]

here's the yaml that I build

[image: yaml]

I do not know the problem...anyone can help?

firewall is inactive
I do not expect what is the problem...

Comment: Did you add your key in Gitlab profile?

Comment: `ssh -T git@serverIP -p 5022` asks for a passphrase. I'm not sure if `git clone` allows `ssh` to ask for a passphrase. Use `ssh-agent` to allow `ssh` to use the key without a passphrase.

Comment: of course, I added my ssh key on gitlab site. I'm not sure how to change that connect without a passphrase on gitlab ssh but I will remake the ssh key from my pc without passphrase. I'm not sure it's gonna work. anyway, thank you for your advise

Comment: thx phd. I remade ssh key that remove the passphrase. now it is working. thx a lot. I don't know how to select the answer that you wrote. if it's possible let me know

Comment: I meant using [`ssh-agent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git+ssh-agent) to store passphrase but if a passwordless key works — let it be. You cannot accept a comment and I'm too lazy to write an answer here. :-)